# What does "EM grade" mean

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm looking at purchase orders and I see purchases for chemicals like the following.

Glutaraldehyde, EM Grade, 25%

What does the "EM Grade" mean in this text? It says that it's recommended for histological or immunological techniques, but how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly purified, typically distilled into glass ampoules and sealed under an inert atmosphere.  Suitable for use in **E**lectron **M**icroscopy.

Answer (score 3):

EM grade is a label for chemicals used in electron microscopy.